# Chrome browser issue: Cannot click any links on my website

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

This issue is only happening in Chrome on my Ubuntu 12 machine. 
In some versions of our website, I cannot click on any links. I can click and focus on textboxes and type text but cannot click a button or link. And since I am the only one complaining in the whole company, it is an issue on my machine, somewhere. How do I debug it?
Same website works perfectly fine in Mozilla firefox.

Chrome version: Version 30.0.1599.66
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I already re-installed chrome but of no use. How can narrow down the problem?

Comment: Have you edited your hosts-file to block advertising domains?

Comment: No. The website works fine in firefox on this machine. It also works fine on chrome on my other machines. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdBlocker Plus plugin was the problem. I probably had different settings on different machines and browsers hence I had different experience in Firefox vs. Chrome.

While debugging this, I thought that there is one plugin which gives similar functionality (i.e., the content is visible but some actions don't work OR the content is hidden altogether). Then I thought of ADP and disabled it in my addons.

Comment: I had this problem for couple of weeks and it's amazing how posting on stackexchange solves the problem.